# Checking if a preference relation admits a utility function

Tags: relations, economics

**Setting:** We have two choices of goods $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ from the set of choices $[-1,1]^2$. Moreover, we have the following preference relation $$(x_1,y_1)\mathcal{R}(x_2,y_2)\iff |x_1|\geq|x_2|\>\>\text{or}\>\> |y_1|\geq|y_2|$$

**Question:** We have to check if there exists a utility function reprensation of this preference relation.

**My attempt:** So from what I have learned, we know that a preference relation admits a utility function representation *if* it is rational (reflexive, complete, transitive) and continuous. I have found that this preference relation is not transitive, but this does not mean that there does not exist a utility function representation, because the aforementioned statement is not an *if and only if* statement.

Moreover, I thought we could try to derive a contradiction from the fact that if there exists a utility function $u$ representation of the preference relation, then we have $$(x_1,y_1)\mathcal{R}(x_2,y_2)\iff u(x_1,y_1)\geq u(x_2,y_2)$$
I tried to use the fact that the relation is not transitive to derive a contradiction by using the statement above, but was unsuccessful.

Sadly, these are the two main theorems/propositions that I've learned to solve these problems.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of a utility function $u$ implies transitivity. Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be objects (pairs, in your example) for which $ARB$ and $BRC$. Then 
$$
u(A) \ge u(B) \text{ and } u(B) \ge u(C)
$$
so
$$
u(A) \ge u(C) 
$$
so $ARC$.

Since you have an instance that contradicts transitivity there can be no utility function.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I came up with also, but I wasn't sure if it was a complete proof. Thanks alot!